# AS3 - Yellow focus rect

Tags: actionscript-3

How to set the yellow focus rect to a movieclip to enable tab navigation? 
This is my current code:

```
mymc.tabEnabled = true
stage.focus = mymc
```

Thanks

Comment: change the border color or the stroke color

Answer (score 1):

try setting the focusrect property of your display object to true.
In your case:

```
mymc.focusRect = true;
```

Here is the relevant note in adobe documentation about the focusRect property.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#focusRect